# Call to undefined function curl_init() - with WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

I'm trying to get cUrl to work, and I'm stumped.

I've uncommented `extension=php_curl.dll` in the `php.ini` file and checked that `php_curl.dll` exists in the directory that `extension_dir` points to. I've also checked that the `php.ini` in the Apache directory is right.

I've copied the `libcurl.dll`'s to Windows/System32, Windows/SysWOW64 and `wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3`

And I've restarted the services every time.

And still I get the `Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()`. Curl doesn't show up when I run a `phpInfo()`. But when I look in the WAMP-menu PHP->PHP extensions `php_curl` does has a checkmark.

Any hints?

Edit:

@Daniel_M: The loaded ini is the one in the Apache directory, and `extension=php_curl.dll` has been uncommented, and `extension_dir` does point to the `php/php5.4.3/ext` directory where the `php_curl.dll` (and `libcurl.dll`) are located.

@ficuscr: I've copied the `libcurl.dll v.7.27.0` all over the place. Where should I place it?

In general: When `php_curl` is unchecked in the `PHP > PHP Extensions menu`, the fatal error is preceeded by:
`SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for`. This doesn't happen when `php_curl` is checked. The fatal error message is the same in either case. A clue?

Comment: I think you're editing the wrong `php.ini`. You can see the loaded ini file in `phpinfo();`

Comment: Probably missing libcurl dependencies.   PHP 5+ requires a libcurl version 7.10.5 or greater.

Comment: Going with Daniel on this.  Also check `extension_dir` in your phpinfo output.  No need to guess where PHP is looking.

Comment: I got the same error and this SO link helped me solve the issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234239/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-error-with-wamp

Answer (score 88, accepted):

WAMP 2.2 comes with a wrong cURL extension. You should download the fixed file from the following link:
http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/. Then replace the file **php_curl.dll** into **/php5.4.3/ext/**.

Comment: Would have loved to find this comment 5 hours ago. Many thanks.

Comment: great answer! had the exact same problem and that fixed it. @Rubberduck should accept it. Just make sure to scroll down on the page to "Fixed curl extensions"

Comment: Some me a lot of time searching around for the fix. Thanks!  Agree, that this answer should be accepted.

Comment: Thanks! One wonders why this problem has still not been fixed in the distribution....

Comment: After spending hours in restarting wamp and copy-pasting dlls here and there, finally solved with this. Thanks!!

Comment: After reading hundreds of answers "Enable the cURL extension by uncommenting the `extension=php_curl.dll` entry in the **php.ini** file", it has finally been solved for me this way!

Comment: This is the correct solution.  After a ton of digging around this was the fix that worked.

Comment: Thanx for saving lot of hours. Works perfectly.
having 5.3.13 version. 1st copied php_curl-5.3.13-nts-VC9-x64 and it didn't worked the replaced php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64....and whoi..la.... it worked. Though, i do not know difference. If some one can enlighten it.

Comment: Simply replacing `(wamp_folder)\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext\php_curl.dll` with the downloaded one solved that problem (after enabling curl extension in php.ini) - Thanks you!

Comment: @TechCare99 I had the same issue. It worked for me too.

Comment: How about a fix for PHP version 7.3.8...?

Answer (score 14):

Click on WAMP Icon > PHP > PHP Extensions > check php_curl.

If it's checked uncheck it, check it again, and Restart all services. Should work.

If it still not working reinstall WAMP. Simple as it is.

Comment: Doesn't he say he tired that in last paragraph?

Comment: Interesting.. I tried to uncheck it and check it again, just for kicks. When I "unchecked" it, the service appeared to restart, but when I went into the Extensions menu, php_curl was still checked (therefore the airquotes). When I tried again, I got an error message: "Could not execute menu item (internal error) [EAccessViolation] Access violation at address 00403A56 in module 'wampmanager.exe'. Read of address 84104888", but the checkmark did disappear.

Comment: Finally I tried checking it again. Still had to do it a couple of times before the checkmark actually appeared. And it still doesn't work.

Comment: did you just try to reinstall wamp?

Answer (score 8):

For me this did the trick: http://www.phpmind.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp/

1) Close WAMP (if running)

2) Navigate to WAMP\bin\php(your version of php)\

3) edit php.ini

4) Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll

5) Navigate to WAMP\bin\Apache(your version of apache)\bin\

6) edit php.ini

7) Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll

8 ) Save both

9) Restart WAMP

Comment: Thanks man, this helped me. I didn't know that php.ini within WAMP is duplicated... which wasted 2 hours of my time -_-

Comment: In my windows, the two files are linked.  When I edit one, the other one is also automatically edited.