# Call to undefined function curl_init() error with WAMP

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I know that it's a very often asked problem, but I've tried all that I found and it still doesn't work.

I use WAMP 2.2 on Windows 7 (64 bits), and PHP 5.4.3. When I call curl_init() in localhost, I've this error message :

```
Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

What I've done :

- Check php_curl in PHP extensions of WAMP
- Restart WAMP many times
- Remove ; before extension=php_curl.dll in my two php.ini files
- Check extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/" in my two php.ini files
- Restart WAMP many times
- Change the DLL for this supposedly corrected DLL http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/
- Restart WAMP many times

And when I call php_info(), I cannot find curl...

Comment: might be dll is missing

Comment: I think the extension might have been damaged. Can you check the apache error log to see what is the error when you restart wamp ?

Comment: The Apache error log shows the same error.

Answer (score 5):

Go to [this link](http://www.anindya.com) download *php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip* under "Fixed curl extensions:" and replace the php_curl.dll in ext folder. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Do as 4life suggests, but make sure you get the dll called 
php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip

do not try to use the one called 
php_curl-5.4.3-nts-VC9-x64.zip

WAMP requred Thread Safe dll's and the -nts- stands for Not-Thread_Safe

Answer (score 1):

My late reply may be useful to someone.

During my experience of this issue, I found that none of the suggestions here nor on other forums resolved it.

In my case I had installed the **Wamp folder** outside of the **Program Files** folder, however the **php.ini** file incorrectly referenced `C:\Program Files\wamp` in multiple places.

Therefore, amending the path in **php.ini** in several places resolved my issue.

To achieve this:

- Load **php.ini** into your favourite text editor
- Search for each instance of **"Program Files"**
- Update the filepath for each one
- Save the changes to make them permanent.

Answer (score 0):

for me, I have wampp installed, none of the former worked. Curl worked only when I clicked the wamp icon and enabled the curl module from there. So left click wamp, choose php extensions and choose curl from there. good luck