# Call to undefined function curl_init() PHP5.6.7 WAMP

Tags: php, apache, curl, twilio

My WAMP curl is not working and not showing up in the phpinfo()

**My system**
Windows 7 64 bit
php-5.6.7-Win32-VC11-x64
WAMP 2.5 
Apache 2.4.9  64bit VC 11

I have followed the steps FROM `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076641/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-with-wamp`

and read to update the the php_curl.dll From the URL `http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/`

but there are none for php5.6.7.

I feel like Im having the same issue. My WAMP is Checked on PHP>PHP Exten>php_curl and openssl.

ALL the php.ini have the `;` deleted from apache and php.ini and phpForApache.ini

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll

; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
 extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.7/ext/"
; On windows:
 extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.7/ext/"
```

This is the php Error Log:

```
[26-Mar-2015 20:49:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic    library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.7/ext/php_curl.dll' - The specified module could   not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[26-Mar-2015 20:49:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic    library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.7/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could    not be found.

in Unknown on line 0
```

Were can i download a new php_curl.dll for PHP 5.6.7 VC11

Comment: Have you looked all the articles on the right under "Linked" and "Related" ? It's a common problem with WAMP.

Comment: I have look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076641/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-with-wamp?lq=1

Comment: And the answer was to download a new php_curl.dll file from the website. This is why im asking does any one know were to download this file for a php 5.6.7

Comment: You could try downloading PHP and grabbing the dll from there: http://windows.php.net/download#php-5.6

Comment: Ok I just tried this with the Non Thread Safe, and Thread Safe didnt work.

Comment: I'm assuming you have, but have you checked that the dll is in the folder it's looking for it in (as per the error message)?

Comment: yes i have checked and they were there. i can see it also in the PHP> php extensions on wamp menu

Answer (score 3):

This isnt a problem with WAMP exactly, but more about something it doesn't do. The new versions of `php_curl.dll` have dependencies. Specifically `libssh2.dll`. In WAMP you can find them in `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.7` .

You need to insure that `libssh2.dll` is in your system PATH (or copy it into the ext directory in WAMP. (Older versions used dependencies that were in the ext directory). Unfortunately WAMP doesn't do this for you, so you have to do it manually.  That should fix the problem.

Comment: I will look it this later today

Comment: in my system path should i put in "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.7" or C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.7\libssh2.dll

Comment: I have added 'libssh2.dll' into my 'system Path' and 'EXT' it has removed the error: 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.7/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.'

Comment: The only error i have now is: [06-Apr-2015 16:36:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.7/ext/php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0