# Call to undefined function curl_init() in WAMP server 3

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I have been digging in StackOverflow for hours now but I still didn't manage to resolve this :(

I want to do a POST request with Curl to get an Auth token, but even though I:

- Made sure `extension=php_curl.dll` is not commented out
- Tried different versions of PHP
- Downloaded the fixed curl extension and replaced it ([reference](https://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/))

My code:

```
  function getToken() {
    echo "start gettoken";

    $jsonStr = http_build_query(Array(
        "client_id" => "***",
        "scope" => "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
        "client_secret" => "***",
        "grant_type" => "client_credentials"
    ));
    $headers = Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    $ch = curl_init("https://login.microsoftonline.com/***.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonStr);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $token = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "test after curl";
    var_dump($token);
    echo $token;
    return $token;

    curl_error($ch);


}
```

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function curl\_init() - with WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076641/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-with-wamp)

Comment: I already tried all the suggestions

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile This is not a duplicate. Y_Lakdime already tried the solutions offered in that post, but none of them worked. that's why he created a new post

Comment: @Y_Lakdime Did you ever get a solution to this issue? I am having same problem today in 2022. I am using WAMPServer with PHP 7.4.26

Answer (score 0):

Enable `php_curl.dll` extension, seems like it's disabled. You can verify it by using

```
echo phpinfo();
```

or directly access the php.ini to check if it' disabled.

stop `wamp` server, open `php.ini`, search for this `extension=php_curl.dll` and uncomment it.

Save the file and restart the server.

Comment: sorry i meant to say i already made sure it is not commented out ! , i have updated my question

Comment: can you please tell me the version of php?

Comment: 5.5.38 is the version i use now

Answer (score -1):

For me this did the trick: http://www.phpmind.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp/

1) Close WAMP (if running)

2) Navigate to WAMP\bin\php(your version of php)\

3) edit php.ini

4) Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll

5) Navigate to WAMP\bin\Apache(your version of apache)\bin\

6) edit php.ini

7) Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll

8 ) Save both

9) Restart WAMP

Comment: thanks for your response, but as I mentioned in the question i already tried that :)

Comment: currently running on php 5.538

Comment: can you please show me screenshot of php.ini file ?